# Where is my mistake in this DFA minimization?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm currently having trouble minimizing my DFA.

I have the following graph: (ignore the numbers after ":")

[image]

Using the table minimization method I reached: (x is distinguishable, O is non-distinguishable)

[image]
However whenever I actually minimize the graph, it is disconnected or is just impossible to actually minimize.

My process (ie. for {q1, q9}):

```
q9 - 0 -> q11
q1 - 0 -> q2

therefore
{q1, q9) is distinguishable
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this / where I made a mistake with my minimization process?

Comment: It appears you do not have an equivalence relation, which it should be.  If 1 is non-distinguishable from 4 and 4 is non-distinguishable from 10, then 1 should be non-distinguishable from 10 as well.

Comment: @RolfHoyer From your feedback, I retraced into http://puu.sh/hdRBt/48c6319866.png but it still creates an invalid minimized DFA.

Comment: Now the results you've shown so far look OK to me, but you'll need to provide elaboration on your further steps for feedback to be possible.

Comment: @RolfHoyer from the graph, I combine (1,4) and (2,8). Since 4 has already been combined, isnt it impossible to combine (4,10)? or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @RolfHoyer I tried combining 1,4,10 but this results in http://puu.sh/heo6q/0c3b6533ee.png
which is not a DFA as there is q1-0->q2 and q1-0>q7

Comment: @RolfHoyer q10 -0-> q8, q10-0>q3, since q10 isi combined with q1 and q4 this occurs

Comment: The q10 -0->q8 and q10-0->q2 is a problem that can be fixed by identifying q2 and q8, which also needs to be done to get the minimal DFA (the linked image should have  q10 -0->q8  instead of q10 -0->q7)

Comment: @RolfHoyer Thank you for your amazing help, I wish I could buy you a beer or pizza :) Could you reply as an answer so I can credit you?